# How to identify deleted product

Tags: magento

I have problem with magento database and deleted items, I want to find all deleted items, so I have a question: in which magento database table, can I find field which identify deleted item from the shop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, when you delete a product in Magento, the product will be removed completely from the database. The deleted products are not kept in the database, and there is no way to get a list of deleted products or to undelete any of them.

Instead of deleting products, what you are probably looking for is to change the status of products, i.e. to enable or disable products. A disabled product, for example, will not be shown in the front-end, while the product is still retained in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a product via the Magento backoffice will completely remove it from the system. Magento does not hold a table that contains the "deleted products".

Answer (score 1):

Performed this query:

```
SELECT * FROM index_event where entity = 'catalog_product' and entity_pk = [product_id];
```

to identify the deleted product. Like @Prince said, all events are registered at `index_event` table. Including the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Magento holds status information about which products added or deleted in index_event table.